# IE9 weird issue

Tags: css, layout, internet-explorer-9

On http://recessionitis.com/ in the right sidebar there are some deals loaded with javascript... But, after those deals are loaded, the footer is half covered by the content background. However, with the developer tools, if I do any change, the footer comes back to normal. Same thing if I zoom in or out.

Anyone knows how to fix it? I want the footer to be in the right place even after the deals are loaded.

This issue happens only with IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#footer-content{
position: relative;
}
```

Add this CSS....